# Python парсинг песен вк

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте

задача стоит запарсить песни с вк. Проблема в том, что не авторизованным пользователям не видно аудиозаписи, даже если страница полностью открыта. Нужно парсить с авторизацией. Пытался через VkApi, но не знаю как перевести в сессию. Пытался найти решение, но все решения связаны со СВОЕЙ страницей, а мне нужно именно чужую.
Может есть другое решение? Нужно именно запарсить аудио чужой страницу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.